# Using aptitude to install extra php modules (after php has already been installed)?

Tags: ubuntu, php5, fastcgi, aptitude

I recently setup an Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS server for a client which uses a PHP based forum. It's all gone well, but now it seems I need to install a new php module to enable spell checking in the forum (the forum is [Simple Machines Forum](http://www.simplemachines.org/))

So when I first setup the server, I installed like this:

```
sudo aptitude -y install php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-suhosin php5-gd
sudo aptitude -y install php5-fpm php5-cgi php-pear php5-memcache php-apc
```

Now it seems I need 'php5-pspell' as well. But because this server is now live and working, I'm worried that I won't do this right and mess something up...

Can I just do this and then restart the php5-fpm service to make it enabled?

```
sudo aptitude -y install php5-pspell
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

?

Many thanks, James

Comment: A couple things.  You seem not very confident about working on your system..  This probably means you should setup a virtual machine that mirrors your production system that you can test and experiment on.  Second it seems like you may not have a backup, and restore system figure out.  You should figure out backup and restore from bare-metal ASAP, setting up a VM will help with this.

Comment: @Zoredache When you say a virtual machine, do you literally mean a Ubuntu Server 10.04 setup through something like virtualbox? The server is on Linode that has a pretty comprehensive backup system, which I have confidence in. But you are right, I don't have major confidence right now, this is my first (very busy) website I've migrated to it's own VPS from a MediaTemple Grid shared server. It's all gone well (after much research) but it makes sense to have some like a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command to install the package looks fine.  But you most likely need to restart Apache, and not a service named php5-fpm.

Comment: Excellent. I'm not using Apache, I have Nginx and a thing called PHP-FPM (basically PHP with FastCGI baked in, so to speak).

Comment: Actually, you don't need to restart anything. PHP keeps absolutely no state between webpage launches - configuration changes and module installs take place immediately, automatically.